# Why must thrown objects be copy-initialized?

Tags: c++, exception, c++14

Exceptions use the statical type of an object to *copy-initialize* the thrown object. For instance:

```
struct foo
{
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    throw foo();
}
```

`Clang++ --std=c++14` complains that the explicitly-deleted copy constructor can't be used. Why can't it be move-initialized instead?

Comment: I can't delete it anymore because it has answers but I'm voting to close as off-topic because of a "simple typographic error". My problem wasn't as trivial as this one, but I clearly just forgot to create a move constructor.

Comment: Thanks to your question I have learnt something. Please don't vote to close it, and by all no means don't delete it!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can't be move constructed because the type has no move constructor. A deleted copy constructor suppresses the implicit move constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Modify the code to the following:

```
struct foo
{
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo&) = delete;
    foo(foo&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    throw foo();
}
```

Read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), the section "Implicitly-declared move constructor".

Answer (score 4):

Because    `foo(foo&& );` is missing. By `delete`ing the copy constructor you've supressed move constructor as well.

Comment: The move constructor is not deleted, just absent.

Comment: @JonathanWakely what's 'not deleted, just missing'? Deleting copy constructor implictly deletes move constructor as well

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Two slightly different senses of "deleted". I think better be explicit what one can and cannot do. Such as defining a move constructor.

Comment: @SergeyA, No, it doesn't. A deleted move constructor would participate in overload resolution. An absent one doesn't. The difference is important.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, since "deleted" is a technical term defined by the C++ standard it's best to avoid using that word to mean "not present", no?

Comment: Well, yes, I agree with that. I just think that *also*, your comment was a bit perplexing to SergeyA. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The applicable phrasing from the standard (§[class.copy]/9) looks roughly like this (well, exactly like this, as of N4296):

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if:
>
> - X does not have a user-declared copy ctor,

[...]

This applies because defining the copy ctor as deleted still means you've declared the copy ctor.